# Efficient method of checking if a set is symmetric

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to write a validator that checks for rooms parsed from a JSON using Gson, that for every pair of rooms A and B that, if you can get from A to B, then you can get from B to A.

Here's the format for the JSON: 
https://jsfiddle.net/tgtbqzky/

```
{
  "initialRoom": "MatthewsStreet",
  "rooms": [
    {
      "name": "MatthewsStreet",
      "description": "You are on Matthews, outside the Siebel Center",
      "directions": [
        {
          "direction": "East",
          "room": "SiebelEntry"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "SiebelEntry",
      "description": "You are in the west entry of Siebel Center.  You can see the elevator, the ACM office, and hallways to the north and east.",
      "directions": [
        {
          "direction": "West",
          "room": "MatthewsStreet"
        },
        {
          "direction": "Northeast",
          "room": "AcmOffice"
        },
        {
          "direction": "North",
          "room": "SiebelNorthHallway"
        },
        {
          "direction": "East",
          "room": "SiebelEastHallway"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "AcmOffice",
      "description": "You are in the ACM office.  There are lots of friendly ACM people.",
      "directions": [
        {
          "direction": "South",
          "room": "SiebelEntry"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "SiebelNorthHallway",
      "description": "You are in the north hallway.  You can see Siebel 1112 and the door toward NCSA.",
      "directions": [
        {
          "direction": "South",
          "room": "SiebelEntry"
        }, 
        {
          "direction": "NorthEast",
          "room": "Siebel1112"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Siebel1112",
      "description": "You are in Siebel 1112.  There is space for two code reviews in this room.",
      "directions": [
        {
          "direction": "West",
          "room": "SiebelNorthHallway"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "SiebelEastHallway",
      "description": "You are in the east hallway.  You can see Einstein Bros' Bagels and a stairway.",
      "directions": [
        {
          "direction": "West",
          "room": "SiebelEntry"
        },
        {
          "direction": "South",
          "room": "Siebel1314"
        },
        {
          "direction": "Down",
          "room": "SiebelBasement"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Siebel1314",
      "description": "You are in Siebel 1314.  There are happy CS 126 students doing a code review.",
      "directions": [
        {
          "direction": "North",
          "room": "SiebelEastHallway"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "SiebelBasement",
      "description": "You are in the basement of Siebel.  You see tables with students working and door to computer labs.",
      "directions": [
        {
          "direction": "Up",
          "room": "SiebelEastHallway"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I was wondering if the way to go would be two nested for loops, wherein the outer for loop would loop through all the rooms, the inner would loop through every direction possible inside each loop, and then I would add each pair I get into an ArrayList.

If I encounter something that is already present, I would remove it from the ArrayList, and if at the end of my for loops, the ArrayList still contains an element, that means that it's corresponding pair wasn't present, and therefore the JSON is invalid. If size of the ArrayList is zero, then the data is valid.

Does anyone have a more efficient method of solving this problem? I feel like since it's essentially proving if a given set is symmetric, there must be a more optimized method.

Comment: you do have a code to deserialize the json to a class right?

Comment: Yes, I do, I have all the classes and functions.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to validate the symmetry of your set by defining a "canonical name" of a pair of rooms, say, by sorting room names in the pair alphabetically, and mapping all room pairs to their canonical names:

```
static String canonicalName(String roomA, String roomB) {
    if (roomA.compareTo(roomB) < 0) {
        return roomA + "|" + roomB;
    } else {
        return roomB + "|" + roomA;
    }
}
```

This will produce the same key `"AcmOffice|MatthewsStreet"` for a pair of rooms where one of them is `"AcmOffice"`, and the other one is `"MatthewsStreet"`, regardless of the order.

Now you can map them to lists, like this:

```
Map<String,List<String>> mp = new HashMap<>();
for (PairOfRooms pair : allRoomPairs) {
    String key = canonicalName(pair.roomA, pair.roomB);
    List<String> list = mp.get(key);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        mp.put(key, list);
    }
    list.add(pair.roomA + "|" + pair.roomB);
}
```

After going through all pairs, examine the lists inside the map:

- If a list has two different items, everything is fine
- If the list has one item, its symmetric item is missing
- If the list has more than two items, there are duplicates

Comment: Could you explain why this is more efficient than my solution? Is this O(n)? It seems O(n^2) to me. Generating the canonical name set itself would be O(n^2) wouldn't it?

Comment: @franklinsing Why would this be O(N^2), when there's no nested loops, and no O(N) operations inside the only loop in the algorithm?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, I meant generating allRoomPairs. So, wouldn't you do something like have a nested for loop each over rooms.size() to generate all the room pairs?

Comment: @franklinsing You have a list of my-room+(room-n, room-e, room-s, room-w). Each item in this list represents four pairs: (my-room+room-n), (my-room+room-e), (my-room+room-s), and (my-room+room-w). This is O(4*N), which is the same as O(N).

Comment: 1. There aren't just four directions (there are 8 possible), as there are things like northeast 2. Not every room has all eight either, some just have one so how can you make the above pairs?

Comment: The only problem about this solution is that it creates new strings. A better solution is an object which instantiate by reordering as in canonicalName and is used the same way in the rest of the algorithm

Comment: should direction match ? ie A west of B means B east of A ?

Comment: @UmNyobe Yes direction should match, that's the only thing that should, so if you can go from A to B, it means you can go from B to A, in the opposite direction.

Comment: @franklinsing Given a room, make all pairs for it that you can. Once the algorithm is over, each pair has to have an opposite pair in the map. If you also need to check the consistency of directions in each pair, replace `String` in the list with something that carries the direction, and see if paired-up directions are opposite (e.g. N+S, NW+SE, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a proxy object for a pair of room A, B, direction
2. Implement a equals and compareto
3. Implement a method to get the opposite room
4. Put the elements you deserialized in a array.
5. Use a map to check if opposite ways have been found.

It runs in O(n)

Which gives

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class RoomPath implements Comparable<RoomPath> 
{
    String from;
    String to;
    String direction;

   public RoomPath(String A, String B, String dir)
   {
       from = A;
       to = B;
       direction = dir;
   }

   public RoomPath opposite()
   {
        String oppDirection ="";
        switch(direction)
        { 
            case "North" : oppDirection = "South"; break;
            case "South" : oppDirection = "North"; break;
            case "West" : oppDirection = "East"; break;
            case "East" : oppDirection = "West"; break;
        }
        return new RoomPath(to, from, oppDirection);
   }

   public int compareTo(RoomPath other)
   {
        int v1 = from.compareTo(other.from);
        if(v1 == 0)
        {
            v1 = to.compareTo(other.to);
            if(v1 == 0)
            {
                return direction.compareTo(other.direction);
            }
            return v1;
        }
        return v1;
   }

   public bool equals(Object e)
   {
       if (!(e instanceof RoomPath)) return false;
       RoomPath path = (RoomPath )e;
       return compareTo(e) == 0;
   }

    public int hashCode() {
        int dirnumber = 0;
        switch(dirnumber)
        { 
            case "North" : dirnumber = 0; break;
            case "South" : dirnumber = 1; break;
            case "West" : dirnumber = 2; break;
            case "East" : dirnumber = 3; break;
        }

        return (from.hashCode() + 31 * b.hashCode() ) << 2 | dirnumber;
        //left as exercise
        return 0;
    }


}


/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        List<RoomPath > roompaths = ... ; //the parsing function
        List<RoomPath > symetrics = new ArrayList<RoomPath>();
        Map<RoomPath, bool> syms = new HashMap<>();
        for (RoomPath path : roompaths) 
        {
            if(!syms.containsKey(path))
            {
                 syms.put(path, false);
            }

            if(syms.containsKey(path.opposite()))
            {
                symetrics.insert(path);
            }
        }
        bool allok = symetrics.size()*2 = roompaths.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would prefer to transfrom the JSON into some 2d matrix like this :

[image]

Which : W for West, E for Est, N for Nord, S for Sud and X means absence of path

Like that it would be very simple to know if you can reach from one Room to the other Room. you have just to implement some simple loops to iterate over the matrix.